# I can't lock my session anymore on Ubuntu unity

Tags: 20.04, unity, lock-screen

I cannot lock my screen in any way :

- `Crtl + l` or `Super + l` ;
- Clicking on `Lock` in the top right menu (where you can also shut down the computer *etc.*)
- Through commands such as `gnome-screensaver-command -l`

How to solve?

Answer (score 1):

This command can help

```
/usr/bin/dm-tool lock
```

Comment: I get "Not running inside a display manager, XDG_SEAT_PATH not defined"

Comment: please run this command
`cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager`
if you got smth like **lightdm**, then you can try 
`echo $XDG_SEAT_PATH`
if result will be empty, try
`export XDG_SEAT_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0`
and try lock again using dm-tool lock